# How can I take a variable number of files as input for a python script?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, command-line, command-line-arguments

For example I want to be able to run this hypothetical command:

```
$ python script.py *.txt option1 option2
```

And have it execute on every file that matches *.txt

Currently I have only found information on operating on one file at a time

```
from sys import argv

self, file, option1, option2 = argv

perform_operation(file, option1, option2)

#function definition
```

Comment: If you can open one file at a time, and you can write a loop... then you can open multiple files :-). As @sharth shows below, `argv` is a list with `argv[0]` the name of the program and `argv[1:]` being the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` is a list. Let's assume that you are only going to pass filename arguments. If it's more complicated, then go with deets' answer.

```
self = sys.argv[0]
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
```

Now, `arguments` is a list of program arguments. Let's say we want to process them one at a time:

```
for argument in arguments:
    work(argument)
```

Or we want to pass all of them to a function:

```
work(arguments)
```

As to passing `*.txt` as an argument. Your shell (before your program even runs) will do most of the work for you.

If I run, `python program.py *.txt` where `*.txt` refers to 3 text files, then my shell will expand that such that my program will see `python program.py a.txt b.txt c.txt`.

Comment: I am accepting a variable number of file names and then two more arguments. The script I am writing is supposed to go through each file and replace any text matching the first argument with the second argument. The solution you provided above will work for me, because I can always assume in this case that the last two arguments are not file names. Thank you!

Comment: If you know for sure that they are always the last two arguments, then you can grab the filenames by doing: `sys.argv[1:][:-2]`. But once you start adding command line arguments, I'd strongly recommend using `ArgumentParser` as shown in deets' answer.

Comment: That could be shortened to just sys.argv[1:-2], that's the solution I went with for this script. If I face anything more complicated I'll go with deet's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the argparse-module:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--option1")
parser.add_argument("--option2")
parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+")

opts = parser.parse_args()

print opts.option1
print opts.option2
print opts.files
```

Use like this:

```
 beer:~ deets$ python2.7 /tmp/argparse-test.py  text foo bar baz
 None
 None
 ['text', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

## `multifile.py`

```
"""
Usage:
    multifile.py <file>...
    multifile.py -h

Prints something about all the <file>... files.
"""

def main(files):
    for fname in files:
        print fname

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    files = args["<file>"]
    main(files)
```

## Use it

Install `docopt` first

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Call the command without arguments:

```
$ python multifile.py
Usage:
    multifile.py <file>...
    multifile.py -h
```

Try help

```
$ python multifile.py -h
Usage:
    multifile.py <file>...
    multifile.py -h

Prints something about all the <file>... files.
```

Use it for one file:

```
$ python multifile.py alfa.py 
alfa.py
```

Use it for multiple files, using wildcards:

```
$ python multifile.py ../*.py

    ../camera2xml.py
    ../cgi.py
    ../classs.py
```

## Conclusions

- docopt allows really many more options (see [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt))
- command line parsing can be easy in Python

  - `argparse` seems is standard part of Python since version 2.7
  - `argparse` can do a lot, but requires rather complex calls on many lines
  - `plac` is nice alternative, can server quickly in most cases
  - `docopt` seems to me to be the most flexible and at the same time shortest in required lines of code

Answer (score 0):

## Using `inputfile` from stdlib

There is one library in stdlib, which is often overlooked, called `inputfile`.

It by default handles all input on command line or from stdin as filenames and allows iterating not only over those files, but also over all the lines in it, modifying them, decompressing and many other practical things.

### `filenames.py` - list all the filenames

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print "File name is: ", fileinput.filename()
    fileinput.nextfile()
```

Call it:

```
$ python filenames.py *.txt
File name is: films.txt
File name is: highscores.txt
File name is: Logging.txt
File name is: outtext.txt
File name is: text.txt
```

## `upperlines.py` - print all lines from multiple files in uppercase

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line.upper(),
```

and call it:

```
$ python upperlines.py *.txt
THE SHAWSHANK REDEMPTION (1994)
THE GODFATHER (1972)
THE GODFATHER: PART II (1974)
THE DARK KNIGHT (2008)
PULP FICTION (1994)
JAN HAS SCORE OF 101
PIETER HAS SCORE OF 900
CYRIL HAS SCORE OF 2
2014 APR 11  07:14:03.155  SECTORBLAH
   INTERESTINGCONTENT
   INTERESTING1 = 843
1. LUV_DEV <- HE'S A DEVELOPER
2. AMIT_DEV <- HE'S A DEVELOPER
....
```

## `upperlinesinplace.py` - turn all lines in files into uppercase

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    print line.upper(),
```

### Conclusions

- `fileinput` takes as default argument `sys.argv[:1]` and iterates over all files and lines
- you can pass your own list of filenames to process
- `fileinput` allows inplace changing, filtering, reading file names, line numbers...
- `fileinput` even allows processing compressed files